# Delete specific element from LinkedList....?

Tags: java, algorithm, nullpointerexception, linked-list

I am trying to delete an specific element from the linkedlist, however i am getting null pointer exception. Could any one pls fix my below mentioned code...

```
public void deleteElement(T num)
    {
        Node<T> ele = new Node<T>(num);
        if(head == null){
            System.out.println("Underflow");
            return;
        }
        Node<T> temp = head;
        while(temp != null)
        {
            if(temp.data == num){
                temp.previous.next = temp.next;
                return;
            }
            else
                temp = temp.next;
        }
        size--;
    }
```

Comment: If you are removing the first element, `temp.previous` will be null. You should treat this case separately.

Comment: Kaidul's answer pretty much covers it. I want to add though that you don't need this line: Node<T> ele = new Node<T>(num);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should modify inside your while loop like this:

```
while(temp != null)
{
    if(temp.data == num) {
        if(temp.previous != null) {
            temp.previous.next = temp.next;
        }
        // you have to link-up the next's previous with temp's previous too 
        if(temp.next != null) {
            temp.next.previous = temp.previous;
        }
        temp = null; // to deference the node and let garbage collector to delete/clear this node
        break; // don't return here otherwise size-- won't execute
    }
    temp = temp.next;
}
```

Before referencing `temp.next` and `temp.previous` as lvalue you should check whether they are `null` otherwise it will throw `NullPointerException`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It is still not deleting the specific element. Instead it is printing the list as it...And i have doubts with the second if-loop, since "temp.next.previous" refers to temp only.

Comment: Hi @aman_coder The above code unlinks the temp node with both next and previous and ties link between previous and next in both direction. I am not seeing any bug here. Can you please share your complete code with Node<T> data structure?

Comment: Hi @Kaidul Islam, please find the complete code below.             
    public class DoubleLinkedList<T> {public class Node<T>
 {T data;
 Node<T> previous, next;
 public Node(T data)
  {this.data = data;
   previous = null;
   next = null;
  }}
 Node<T> head;
 public void deleteElement(T num)
 {Node<T> temp = head;
  while(temp != null)
 {if(temp.data == num) {
         if(temp.previous != null) {
             temp.previous.next = temp.next;}
          if(temp.next != null) {
             temp.next.previous = temp.previous;
         }return;
     }temp = temp.next;
 }}

Comment: @aman_coder your `Node` class and `deleteEelement` method seems okay. Provide the driveer program(the code to create the linked list and calling deleteElement method)

Comment: Insert method:

int size = 0;;
 public void insert(T num)
 {
  Node<T> ele = new Node<T>(num);
  /*ele.next = head;
  if(!(head == null))
   head.previous = ele;
  head = ele;
  ele.previous = null;*/
  
  if(head == null)
   head = ele;
  else
   {
   ele.next = head;
   ele.previous = null;
   head = ele;
   }
  size++;
 }

Main method:

public static void main(String args[])
 {
  DoubleLinkedList<Integer> d = new DoubleLinkedList<Integer>();
  d.insert(11);
  d.insert(14);
  d.insert(7);
  d.insert(17);
  d.deleteElement(14);
}

Comment: This is wrong. It should be `else { ele.next = head; head.previous = ele; head = ele; }`

Comment: so finally i am able to delete all the elements(one by one), however the last element which becomes the head is not getting deleted with this....any suggestions.

Comment: Hey @Kaidul Islam, thank you for the help...:) it looks good now however just added one extra condition

if(temp.previous != null) {
             temp.previous.next = temp.next;
         }
         else{
          head = temp.next;
         }

Answer (score 0):

You have to find `Node` object whose `data` is equal to `T num`. Use such loop:

```
for (Node<T> x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
                if (num.equals(x.data)) {
                    unlink(x);
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

Where first is `pointer` to first node. In method remove you have to unlink found `Node x` from linked list:

```
T remove(Node<T> x) {
        // assert x != null;
        final T element = x.data;
        final Node<T> next = x.next;
        final Node<T> prev = x.prev;

        if (prev == null) {
            //if x is first node(head)
            first = next;
        } else {
            // link x.next to x.prev.next
            prev.next = next;
            //unlink x
            x.prev = null;
        }

        if (next == null) {
           //if x is last node(tail)
            last = prev;
        } else {
            // link x.prev to x.next.prev
            next.prev = prev;
            //unlink x
            x.next = null;
        }
// reset data
        x.data = null;
        size--;
        return element;
    }
```